# Joomla + Jomsocial Custom Profile Help! - Creating Prefered Method of Contact Field Group

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I'm going to try to create a "Whats the best way for us to contact you?" Field/Field Group where the user/customer can choose between a phone call, a text message, or an email. This would be displayed on the second page of registration, and/or available to create/edit on the user/customers profile page inside JomSocial. The goal is to use the information provided by the user/customer so that we know the best way they would like to be contacted.

I would be using the phone number and/or email that is supplied by the user during the registration process

Here is an example of my goal, please understand that is is not supposed to be actual code or anything, I'm just attempting to explain how I would like to go about this:

"Whats the best way for us to contact you?"
"1st Contact Method Choice:"
 - (drop down) "Phone Call | Text Message | Email"
 - If Phone Call,    (drop down) "{display given phone #1} |  {display
   given phone    #2}"
 - If Text Message, (drop down) "{display given phone #1} |  {display
   given phone #2}"
 - If Email, just show "{display email given}"
"2nd Contact Method Choice:" (do the same as 1st choice above) 
"3rd Contact Method Choice:" (do the same as 1st choice    above)

Here is my example of what the output would look like when its filled out

Whats the best way for us to contact you?
    1st Choice: Text Message - 555-555-5555
    2nd Choice: Email - email@example.com
    3rd Choice: Phone Call - 555-555-5555

I'm currently using JoomlaXi's JomSocial Profile Types (JSPT), but I'm not too sure if that even matters in this situation. I also am unsure if there already is a plug-in or extension to solve this problem, I've looked but I figured asking here would yield the best results.

Thank you in advanced - any and all help is welcomed and appreciated

Comment: JomSocial is a commercial extensions and therefore you would be best off seeking help from the developers or forum.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to customize or create a new field type in:

```
components/com_community/libraries/fields
```

Then either in the class getFieldHTML() method or directly in the

```
components/com_community/templates/default/register.profile.php
```

or, if you use a custom template,

```
components/com_community/templates/your_jomsocial_template/register.profile.php
```

you have to input all your jQuery or old-school javascript to implement the functionality.  It is safe to use the field id as jQuery('#field11')

**Disclaimer**

This is a (minor) jomsocial core hack, document it well in your git push/svn commit and in the project docs, as updating the component later may break this.

Remember to test both save and display.

There are several posts in jomsocial forums but my saved links are 404 now, just login and search for "custom profile field", some post like this could help you get started in the right direction:

http://www.jomsocial.com/forum/technical-issues/3286-how-to-add-custom-table-fields-and-info-on-profile-page#21074